# Bacterial Sampling : Dependent event

Tags: probability, sampling, independence

I have a question regarding distribution of bacteria in wells:
I have a tube that contains 200ul of 5000CFU/ml of bacterial solution.

If I have 20 tubes to which I will add 10ul of bacterial sample from the 200ul original tube, what is the probability that the conc of bacteria in the well is between 30-60? I reason I have problem with this is because, the 10ul taken out is not put back in there, so this should be considered a dependent event, so I can't use the Poisson's distribution, right? How to calculate this probability then?

Comment: What is CFU? What are the units of "conc of bacteria in the well is between 30-60"? Does "ul" mean $\mu l = 0.001 ml$?

Comment: CFU is colony forming units, simply speaking, it is the number of bacteria.By 30-60 conc, I meant, between 30 to 60 bacteria in a tube (with volume of 10ul) and yes, ul is microliter =0.001ml.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have $1000$ bacteria in your big tube. Is there any variation in this? If there is then that would push the variance up slightly. Let's assume not.

You could model the number of bacteria in a little tube as a binomial distribution with parameters $1000$ and $\frac{1}{20}$ so with mean $50$ and variance $47.5$.  The probability of having from $30$ through to $60$ inclusive, using R, would be

```
> pbinom(60, 1000, 1/20) - pbinom(29, 1000, 1/20)
[1] 0.9322183
```

while using a Poisson approximation with the same mean (implicitly a slightly higher variance of $50$, slightly reducing the probability of being in a central interval) would give

```
> ppois(60, 50) - ppois(29, 50)
[1] 0.926923
```

or using a Gaussian approximation with a continuity correction and the binomial mean and variance would give

```
> pnorm((60.5 - 50)/sqrt(47.5)) - pnorm((29.5 - 50)/sqrt(47.5)) 
[1] 0.9347156
```

all giving a probability of about $93\%$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is based based on the fact that the sampling into 20 tubes is independent of each other right? what if I am not putting the 10ul solution back into the original tube? So, for example: If the 1st 10ul I take out from my original solution and put into a tube has 60 bacteria, then, the remaining bacteria in the original solution will be 1000-60 = 940, so now if I take 10ul out again into another tube  and that has 40, the remaining bacteria in the solution will be 940-40=900; and so on. So the sampling is dependent event. Will the above formula hold good even then?

Comment: The probabilities above are for a single small tube.  The fact that one small tube's content may be very slightly dependent on another does not affect this.  In fact, if the big tube is a sample from a large well rather than exactly $1000$ bacteria then the small tubes may be very close to independent (and the variance closer to $50$ and the Poisson a better model).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I appreciate it.